# Drawing lines between matching numbers in a two column table

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

I have two lists of numbers of the same length. I want to display the numbers in a table with two columns, one list in each column. I also want to drawn lines between any number in the first column and any matching number in the second column. How can I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
SeedRandom[10];
MatrixForm[
  Join[Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10]}], 
  Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10]}], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {1, 20}]
```

Here is the way I would like my output to look:

[image: Sample list with matches]

Comment: Poor quality, too-localized question.

Comment: I think you are over-reacting, guys. The question could be saved with a little editing, and I think it's part of our job to save it if we can. I have have put my typing fingers to work in this regard, and now I recommend this question be reopened.

Comment: @m_goldberg you may be right. There are a very large number of bad questions being submitted lately and sometimes the urge to close wins out. I still think that this one lacks motivation and is too localized, albeit it is more pleasant to read after your ministrations. I retracted my downvote.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I agree with your assessment of the large number of bad questions. Happens every fall when the academic year begins, doesn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[10];

col1 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10];
col2 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10];

txt = {
   n = Length[col1];
   Text[ToString[#], {1, n--}, {1.5, 0}] & /@ col1,
   n = Length[col2];
   Text[ToString[#], {2, n--}, {-1.5, 0}] & /@ col2};

lines = Cases[
   Outer[
    If[#1[[1]] == #2[[1]],
      Line[{#1[[2]], #2[[2]]}],
      Sequence[]] &, Sequence @@ txt],
   Line[_], Infinity];

Graphics[{txt, Red, Thick, lines},
 ImageSize -> 300,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Add colored lines to show direction of placement between the two lists

    `colored = 
  Table[Which[
    lines[[i, 1, 1, 2]] == lines[[i, 1, 2, 2]], {Blue, lines[[i]]}, 
    lines[[i, 1, 1, 2]] > lines[[i, 1, 2, 2]], {Green, lines[[i]]}, 
    lines[[i, 1, 1, 2]] < lines[[i, 1, 2, 2]], {Red, 
     lines[[i]]}] , {i, Length[lines]}]; 

Graphics[{txt, colored}, ImageSize -> 350, AspectRatio -> 2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = Module[{lst = Join[##], l = Length@#, vertices, edges}, 
    vertices = Labeled[##, Center] & @@@ Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #} &@lst];
    edges = Join @@ Outer[If[#[[2]] == #2[[2]], UndirectedEdge[#[[1]], #2[[1]]], ## &[]]&, 
     vertices[[;; l]],  vertices[[1 + l ;;]]];
    Graph[vertices, edges, VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .05}, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> { _ -> None, Alternatives@@Flatten[List@@@edges] -> "Circle"}, 
     VertexLabelStyle -> {_ -> 14, Alternatives@@Flatten[List@@@edges] -> {Red , 15}}, 
     VertexCoordinates -> Join[Thread[{0, Range[l]/l}], Thread[{1, Range[l]/l}]]]] &;
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[10];
col1 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10];
col2 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 10];

f1[col1, col2]
```

[image]